# PIP command doesn't work inside virtual environment

Tags: python, linux, pip, virtualenv, anaconda

The interpreter I use is

[image]

and it works in virtual environment. I have both anaconda and python interpreter installed in my system

But if I want to install something using pip for instance "Flask" then it happens

[image]

I am using Linux Mint 18.1 Serena"
And the way I tried to create the virtual environment is

[image]

Lastly there is no space in the directories where I tried to create virtual environment 
Then I tried this [link](http://exponential.io/blog/2015/02/10/install-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-on-ubuntu/)
Specifically the following commands
[image]

All those things didn't solve my problem and lastly I ended with the following errors each time I open my shell
 [image]

Then I change my source of bashrc & bashrc-org to

## virtualenv

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/virtualenvs
source /home/cryptosilicon/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Now get the following error
[image]

How do I correct the error and make the pip work inside virtual environment ?

Comment: I just fixed the last error but still pip doesn't work  in virtual environment

Answer (score 3):

I just solved (or at least found a work-around) for a similar problem.
I am using Linux Mint 18 and python 3.

I was trying to install a dependency inside a Python virtual environment using pip and it would fail (and actually pretty much mess up my whole virtual env).
The message was : "bad interpreter: No such file or directory".

But I noticed that the referenced path was actually truncated at the first space.
So I tested an virtual env in a folder for which path there is no space and it worked.